# Is there a dynamic management view in SQL Server 2005 that pertains to column statistics?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The dynamic management views of SQL Server 2005 can give usage information about table indexes.  Is there a similar method for getting usage information about column statistics?  In specific, I'm curious if some of the older column statistics I've created are still being used.  If not, I'd like to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there isn't. there are however [sys.stats_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187340.aspx) and [sys.stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx) catalog views